# How to get higher weight range for vocabulary

Tags: 7, forms

I found the line in the taxonomy.admin.inc, but i didn`t want to change it in the core. So, How can I get it in my module to override the #delta of the vocabularies?

With the function I didn`t get a solution:

```
function <MYMODULE>_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "taxonomy_overview_vocabularies") {
    foreach ($form as $vocabulary) {
        if(isset($vocabulary['weight']['#delta'])) {
            $vocabulary['weight']['#delta'] = 20;
        };
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to pass value by reference.

```php
function <MYMODULE>_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "taxonomy_overview_vocabularies") {
    foreach ($form as &$vocabulary) {
      if (isset($vocabulary['weight']['#delta'])) {
        $vocabulary['weight']['#delta'] = 20;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Hmm, thats doesn`t solve the problem. The delta is changed in the array, but the weight select list in the vocabulary is still from -10 to 10 ... any other idea?

Comment: I found the copy I copy from you has missing close bracket. I fixed it and tried in my local environment, it does work. Could you try again?

Comment: haha, sry i forgot one referenced value! great, thx a lot!